# how to generate stoppage report in asp.net with c# in vehicle tracking system

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

Hi I am working on the project vehicle tracking system i want to generate stoppage report it was working fine with php and extjs but now am changing the project to asp.net with C#.I have 4 different queries to display the report but in asp.net gridview how can i bind all the 4 different queries to display in gridview with pagination.

Here is my PHP Code

```
$NewID = "";
        $OldID = "";        
         //echo("Select gps_id,lat,lon,tdate,ttime,tdate_time,speed,lname from gps_data where vehicle_no = '$vno' and (CONVERT(tdate_time, DATETIME) between '$FromDate' and '$ToDate') and speed > 1 order by gps_id asc");

    $sql1 = mysql_query("Select gps_id,latitude,longtitude,get_date,get_time,get_date_time,speed,location from gps_data where device_id = '$device_id' and host_name = '". $host  ."' and (CONVERT(get_date_time, DATETIME) between '$FromDate' and '$ToDate') and speed > 1 order by gps_id asc");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql1))
    {

        $NewID = $row[0];
        //echo($OldID);
        if($OldID > 0)
        {
         // echo("Select CONVERT(tdate_time, DATETIME) from gps_data where gps_id = ". $OldID ."");
           $query = mysql_query("Select get_date_time,date_time from gps_data where gps_id = ". $OldID ." and host_name = '". $host  ."'");

           if($result = mysql_fetch_row($query))
           {
              $show_old_get_date_time = $result[0];  
              $old_get_date_time = $result[1];
              //echo($old_get_date_time);
           }

           $query1 = mysql_query("Select get_date_time,date_time from gps_data where gps_id = ". $NewID ." and host_name = '". $host  ."'");
           if($result1 = mysql_fetch_row($query1))
           {
                  $show_new_get_date_time = $result1[0];
                  $new_get_date_time      = $result1[1];
           }

        //echo("Select gps_id,lat,lon,tdate,ttime,tdate_time,speed,lname from gps_data where vehicle_no = '$vno' and gps_id > ". $OldID ." and gps_id < ". $NewID ." and (CONVERT(tdate_time, DATETIME) between '$FromDate' and '$ToDate') order by gps_id asc");
            $sql2 = mysql_query("Select gps_id,latitude,longtitude,get_date,get_time,get_date_time,speed,location from gps_data where device_id = '$device_id' and host_name = '". $host  ."' and gps_id > ". $OldID ." and gps_id < ". $NewID ." and (CONVERT(get_date_time, DATETIME) between '$FromDate' and '$ToDate') order by gps_id asc");
            if($rowA = mysql_fetch_row($sql2))
            {

                $NewLoc = parseD($rowA[7]);
                //echo("SELECT TIMEDIFF('". $new_get_date_time ."','". $old_get_date_time ."')");
                $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF('". $new_get_date_time ."','". $old_get_date_time ."')");  
                    if($rowB = mysql_fetch_row($sql3))
                    {

                            $cnt = $cnt + 1;
                            $DTDiff = $rowB[0];

                            $strBld .= $comm."{slno:\"". $cnt ."\",get_date:\"". $rowA[3] ."\",get_date_time:\"". $show_old_get_date_time." "."-"." ". $show_new_get_date_time ."\",stoppedTm:\"". $DTDiff ."\",loc_name:\"". $NewLoc ."\",latitude:\"".$rowA[1]."\",longitude:\"".$rowA[2]."\"}";
                            $comm = ",";

                    }


            } //while($rowA = mysql_fetch_row($sql2))


        } //if($OldID > 0)

        $OldID = $row[0];   
        //echo($OldID);
    } //while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql1))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide what you have got so far in your ASP ported code so people can see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination is used to display the remaining data. But it seems that you have different cases. You can either write you query with these cases and then union them and bind this query as the data source of the gridview. Or you can set buttons or any other ui control for each case to change the data source of the gridview.

Comment: normally you can union queries like this : select get_date_time,date_time,'new' as type from gps_data where gps_id = "+ NewID +" union all select get_date_time,date_time,'old' as type from gps_data where gps_id = "+ OldID +" but in this case you have different conditions and it may be better to seperate them with different ui controls.

Comment: but since it is a stoppage report of the vehicle i cannot separate them with different UI Controls.This Report should be generated with a single click of the button

Comment: Ok then. You can do it either in the data level by using cases and returning a single result set but in this case you need to have the same columns to union the seperate result sets or else you can use different queries and have different result sets and try to merge them into a single datatable and bind this datatable to the gridview.